# Ridding of the nasty mildew smell throughout the home

Tags: hvac

My aunt turned on her heat and along came the nasty smell of musty mildew, the odor is now taking on the clothes, blankets and pillows in the home ! Please help

Comment: I presume that she's got a forced hot air furnace? That's fairly common when turning on the heat for the first time each fall. Give it a day or two, it should go away.